# Jquery: TableSorter- Date with specic format is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

I am using [Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) plugin to sort the table .
fourth column is date fields having format :

-->**30 Jan 2013**

-->**01 Feb 2013**

when i try to sort format it gives wrong sorting.

My View page:(one of the date column )

```
<td onclick="viewTrainingeDetails(${privateTrainingInstance?.id})"><g:formatDate format="dd MMM yyyy" date="${privateTrainingInstance?.startDate}" /></td>
```

**jquery**

```
 $(function() {
         $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
   });
```

Comment: use beforesort & aftersort event to convert date in unix mode for ex

Comment: I think you should Upvote for the Answerer ! :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try adding this custom parser ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/361/)):

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: "date",
    is: function (s) {
        return false;
    },
    format: function (s, table) {
        return new Date(s).getTime() || '';
    },
    type: "numeric"
});
```

then initialize the plugin like this:

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    headers: {
            5: { sorter: 'date' }
        }
});
```

---

Update: for best results, make sure you are returning a valid date:

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: "date",
    is: function (s) {
        return false;
    },
    format: function (s, table) {
        var date = new Date(s);
        return date instanceof Date && isFinite(date) ? date.getTime() : '';
    },
    type: "numeric"
});
```

Comment: I would like to upvote the answer twice :( this  parser is much simpler and makes a lot of sense than all the other answers in SO related to this issue