# jquery tablesorter sort date dd mmm yyyy

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am pretty new to tablesorter but I have a table with several columns, and the 3rd column is dates, coming back from the DB in the form of `dd mmm yyyy, hh:mm:ss (am/pm)`

For example

```
29 Jul 2013, 1:12:23 PM
2 Aug 2013, 3:59:59 PM
17 Jul 2013, 09:30:00 AM
```

then I sort my table

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter({sortInitialOrder: "desc"}); 
    } 
);
```

but it comes out in "alphabetical order", meaning 29 before 2 before 17, not taking into account the date aspects.

It looks like there is a dateFormat option I can pass in but I can't get it to work.  I know Java has special keys with different meanings [like this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).  Is there anything comparable in tablesorter?  How do I go about making sure the one date column is sorted properly?

I can guarantee that the format will always be as I specified above, and I don't want to change the appearance of the displayed date, just the sorting functionality.

Looks like dateFormat: 'usLongDate' is close to what I need but not working

UPDATE:  I think my problem is that I have more info in the  object than just the date, however I want to sort by *just* the date.  Here is my working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eY8uH/537/).

Comment: similar to previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476899/jquery-tablesorter-date-with-specic-format-is-not-working

Comment: That is the one I was working from.  I have updated my question to further clarify and added a fiddle.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this parser (it's not perfect since it doesn't validate the date, i.e. it will accept a time of `99:99:99`; but then the date parser will return an invalid date and default back to plain text ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eY8uH/538/)):

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: "date",
    is: function (s) {
        return false;
    },
    format: function (s, table) {
        var date = (s + '').match(/(\d{1,2}\s+\w{3}\s+\d{4}),(\s+\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s+[AP]M)/);
        return date ? new Date(date[1] + date[2]).getTime() || s : s;
    },
    type: "numeric"
});
```

---

Update: To elaborate on the regex and answer your comment... basically the regex is matching a pattern: `\d{1,2}` matches any 1 or 2 digits, `\d{4}` matches any 4 digits, `\w{3}` matches any "word" 3 letters in length, `\s+` matches any number of spaces or tabs and `[AP]M` matches `AM` or `PM`.

Now the parenthesis `()` save specific matches - notice that the comma is outside of the parentheses. And note that the first value in the array is the entire string, if it matches. So the first part `date[1]` contains the date portion (e.g. `29 Jul 2013`) and the second part `date[2]` contains the time (e.g. `1:12:23 PM`).

Check out this [basic tutorial on regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html), then try messing around with [this regex tester](http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/regtest.htm).

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you!  Would you be so kind as to give an English explanation as to how this is working?  What is this regex essentially doing?  Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond. I've updated my answer for you.